# How to direct GStreamer log to a file?

Tags: debugging, gstreamer

I want to check the GStreamer log message when running some GUI application. I can not launch the application from the terminal for some error. I can only launch it by clicking.

So can I direct GStreamer log message to a local file in such a use case? Can GStreamer be configured to set a log file?

Thanks
Amanda

Answer (score 11):

The environment variable **GST_DEBUG_FILE** does exactly this.